# How to remove connection time out links form RHEL

Tags: linux, php, httpd, lamp, rhel7

I want **uninstall LAMP from my REDHAT virtual server** and reinstall back it again but i don't have internet access on my server and when i uninstall mysql from my server i getting below error please help me how i do it. I am new in linux server.

[image]

Also please help me **how to install LAMP server on my redhat with out internet**. I searched on google but not found anything for offline server. Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable repositories that are not available, either by editing the yum repo configuration file(s) in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` or by using yum with the **`--disablerepo=repoidglob`** switch

```
yum --disablerepo=zabbix remove mysql
```

Comment: thax for the help...:).. also can you help me how to install LAMP in redhat VM without internet

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your 2nd question, check the requisites here :

[LAMP Server RPM](https://altlinux.pkgs.org/sisyphus/classic-noarch/lamp-server-1.1-alt1.noarch.rpm.html)